# Stationarity of a process

Tags: variance, stationary-processes

I have a process:
$$\epsilon_t=\nu_t\sqrt{\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1}}$$ where $\nu_t$ is a white noise with variance equal to $1$.
My textbook says that the conditional variance of $\epsilon_t$ is not constant, but what can I say about the unconditional variance of $\epsilon_t$?
It is said to me that $E[\epsilon^2_t]=E[\epsilon^2_{t-1}]$ (i.e. $\epsilon_t$ is a stationary process) but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: Is $\nu_t$ independent of $\epsilon_{t-1}$?

Comment: yes, sorry for forgetting to mention it

Comment: Then it obviously holds that $$E[\epsilon^2_t] = E[\nu^2_t(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1})] = E[\nu^2_t]E[\alpha_0 + \alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1}] = 1\cdot \alpha_1^2E[\epsilon^2_{t-1}]$$ So the claim is true iff $\alpha_1 = \pm 1$

Comment: yes it is quite correct (you forgot $+\alpha_0)$ but my doubt is about what the textbook says, I report here what it does in order to compute $E[\epsilon^2_t]$. As you it computes the relation $E[\epsilon^2_t]=\alpha_0+\alpha_1E[\epsilon^2_{t-1}]$ and then it uses the property $E[\epsilon^2_t]=E[\epsilon^2_{t-1}]$ (that I can't understand) and then he can compute $E[\epsilon^2_t]=\frac{\alpha_0}{1-\alpha_1}$

Comment: I guess what's really meant is: What $E[\epsilon^2_t]$ need to fulfill that $\epsilon_t$ become indeed a stationary process (that's why it's used that $E[\epsilon^2_t]=E[\epsilon^2_{t-1}]$, because for a stationary process this has to hold)
And you get: IF it holds $E[\epsilon^2_t]=\frac{\alpha_0}{1-\alpha_1}$ THEN $\epsilon_t$ is a stationary process.

Comment: But can I say a priori that $\epsilon_t$ is stationary for construction since $\nu_t$ is a white noise (i.e. stationary)?